# Android Studio "Resource" Window

Tags: android, android-studio

I have started Android development and I need to access the 'resource' window.  I have searched around and have not found an answer.  What I am doing is I am trying to change the background color of my app using the 'color.xml' file I have created.  The problem is, I cannot find the 'background_color' resource in the 'RelativeLayout' panel in the 'Design' view in Android Studio.  Does anyone know where or how to open this window?!

Sorry for my noobish-ness,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull up the "resources" window, you have to:

1. Open the activity in "Design" mode.
2. Select the "RelativeLayout"
3. Go to "Properties" pane and find whatever property you need.
4. Once selected, click the "..." button.
5. A window appears with a list of all properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a background color of a relativeLayout, you can use the background resource. This can be any of the predefined colors, or a special layout file you made that specifies the shape of the layout, curved edges, etc.

Comment: I know there is a window that is a list of all the resources in a layout.  I want to know how to access that.

Comment: To access a specific resource (color.xml, for example). In the background field of the design tab, you can type @drawable/color if color.xml is in the drawable folder within res. If color.xml is in values, it would be @values/color. In the text part of xml, it would be android:background="@drawable/color"

Comment: I'm not looking for the xml code, though.  I am looking for the window that lets you select a resource and modify it.

Comment: If you want to look at all the possible select-able resources, there are 3 small dots in a box to the right of the background text field. This opens a new window which lists all the resources available. They often have previews which you can take and place into a new file to modify.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I've been looking on Google and various forums for this.